# Set the highlighted item in the comboBox's dropdown list as the current value on cell exit or cell leave

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, datagridcomboboxcolumn

```
private void dataGridViewSales_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
  if (this.dataGridViewSales.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
  {
    ComboBox c = e.Control as ComboBox;
    ((ComboBox)c).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
    ((ComboBox)c).AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    ((ComboBox)c).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
  }
}
```

With the code above, am having a problem where by after making my selection from an auto complete combobox, i loose my selection when i exit the combobox Cell by pressing the Tab key. Some times, the selection is retained, other times the selection is cleared, it sort of happens randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handling the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event resolved the issue, i hope it doesn't result into some other issue though!

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            {
                dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }
        }
```